# Install older version of VirtualBox (4.3.6-91406) on OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I am trying to install VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406 on OS X El Capitan because I want to run an old version of Minix.

It is advised to run my version of Minix on VirtualBox 4.3.6 as it may not be compatible with the newest VirtualBox 5.0.12-104815 and anything between.

### Running the old VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406:

This is what I get when I try to install VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406:

[image: The installation failed.]

### Running latest VirtualBox 5.0.12-104815:

And this is what I get when I try to run my old version of Minix on the latest VirtualBox:

> Implementation of the USB 2.0 controller not found!
>
> Because the USB
>   2.0 controller state is part of the saved VM state, the VM cannot be started. To fix this problem, either install the **'Oracle VM VirtualBox
>   Extension Pack'** or disable USB 2.0 support in the VM settings
>   (VERR_NOT_FOUND).
>
> Result Code:  NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
>   Component:  ConsoleWrap
>   Interface:  IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

[image: Failed to open session ...]

Is there anything I can do about it? I want to run this version of Minix and preferably VirtualBox 4.3.6.

Comment: VirtualBox 4.3.6-91406 is not supported on OS X 10.11.  You need to do as the error message suggests and you may have to discard the suspended state manually if you can't do it through the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the following things:

1. Boot the image on Linux with VirtualBox 4.3.6 installed from a terminal using the following command:

   ```
   $ VBoxSDL --startvm MINIX3 --norawr0 --norawr3 --nohwvirtex
   ```
2. Apply [this patch](https://github.com/Stichting-MINIX-Research-Foundation/minix/commit/92293fafd3877cfbb7bde350a225b2e07e737de1) which resolves the guru meditation problem.

   1. Go to `/usr/src/drivers/e1000` and in the `e1000.c` file you have to replace line

      ```
      e1000_reg_write(e, E1000_REG_MTA + i, 0);
      ```

      with

      ```
      e1000_reg_write(e, E1000_REG_MTA + i * 4, 0);
      ```
   2. Run `make` and `make install` in `/usr/src/drivers/e1000`.
3. Turn off your virtual machine.
4. Copy the whole directory of your virtual machine to OS X.
5. Install latest VirtualBox.
6. Download [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html#extpack) and add this extension to your VirtualBox.
7. Done!